# TypeError and ValueError Proper handling in checking -ve no. and string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to raise or handle exception when a no. is -ve or the value is string.

```
def pallindrome(x):
    try:
        val=int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("x must be integer")
        return 0
    try:
        x<0
    except TypeError:
        print("x must be +ve integer")
        return 0
    temp=x
    rev=0
    while(x>0):
        r=x%10
        rev=rev*10+r
        x=x/10
    if(temp==rev):
        print("pallindrome")
    else:
        print("ne")

pallindrome(-121)       #o/p --ne
pallindrome("vikash")   #o/p--x must be integer
```

Here how to handle negative integer case.
please suggest .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "-ve"?

Comment: I mean to say negative integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need to raise exception when a number is negative you can use simple `if` statement to check that:

```
def pallindrome(x):
    try:
        val=int(x)
        if val<0:
            print("x must be +ve integer")
            return 0
        rev=0
        while val>0:
            r = val%10
            rev = rev*10+r
            val = val/10
        if temp == rev:
            print("pallindrome")
        else:
            print("ne")
    except ValueError:
        print("x must be integer")
        return 0
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to raise `TypeError` exception when the number is negative you can change the code like this:

```
        ...
        if val<0:
            raise TypeError("x must be +ve integer")
            return 0
        ...
    except ValueError:
        print("x must be integer")
        return 0
```

Comment: Is we can use TypeError exception her?

Comment: @VikashKumar If you want to raise TypeError exception you can act like my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function in stead of this try-except block :

```
try:
    x<0
except TypeError:
    print("x must be +ve integer")
    return 0
```

Try this :

```
if x<0:
    print("x must be +ve integer")
    return 0
```

Or if you want to raise some exception, try this out :

```
if x<0:
    raise ValueError("x must be +ve integer")
    return 0
```